# Selected value in dropdown does not seem to be posted

Tags: php, html, forms, post

If this problem/question has already been answered then my apologies. I was not able to find an answer for my problem with an `HTML dropdown`.

I have a form with multiple input fields and text areas and whenever I post this form all these values will get posted. However, I also have a dropdown that I create from my database. This `dropdown` shows up properly but when I post the form this is the only `$_POST` variable in the form that does not seem to get posted. 
This form is used to edit an existing object and make sure the category that object has is automatically selected.

Below is the part of my form with the `dropdown`:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['categoryselect'])) {

    $allcategory = $_SESSION['categoryselect'] ?> 
    <select name="selectedcategory" required="required">

    <?php foreach($allcategory as $category) {

        if ($category->sub_categorie == $selectedproduct->sub_category) {?>

            <option value="<?php $category->sub_category?>"selected="selected">
                <?php echo $category->sub_category?>
            </option>

        <?php } else {?>

            <option value="<?php $category->sub_category?>">
                <?php echo $category->sub_category?>
            </option>

        <?php } 
      } ?>
    </select> 
 <?php } ?>
```

Below is a part of the code that handles the posted form:

```
$name= $_POST['name'];
$name= mysql_escape_string($name);

$sub_category = $_POST['selectedcategory'];
$sub_category = mysql_escape_string($sub_category);

$price= $_POST['price'];
$price= mysql_escape_string($price);
```

The posts for `'name'` and `'price'` are also in the same form with my 'category'
These 2 fields do get posted. My `'category'` however gives an undefined index error. As far as I know this means that the `'category'` does not get posted. But this made me wondering why the other values do get posted and this particular value from a `dropdown` does not.

Comment: you mean dropdown value not stored in database.

Comment: you are using `selectedcategory` and in `$_POST` using `$_POST['category'];`
Keep the same name as you are using in `$_POST` array.

Comment: Storing and retrieving values is not a problem. I have trouble getting the value the user selected in the dropdown to my form handler. It should be posted like all other values but this does not seem to happen.

Comment: you also have a missing `?` in your php close tag ` <option value="<?php $category->sub_category>"selected="selected">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$sub_category = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['selectedcategory']);
$price= mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
```

You can also refactor the code in the frontend like:

```
<select name="selectedcategory" required="required">
<?php 
    foreach($allcategory as $category) {
        echo '<option value="' . $category->sub_category . '"'; 
        if ($category->sub_categorie == $selectedproduct->sub_category) {
            echo 'selected="selected"';
        }
        echo '>' . $category->sub_category . '</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Please **note** that `mysql` functions are deprecated.. use `mysqli` instead..

Comment: Refactoring the code front end made it work. I forgot about the mysqli functions, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sub_category = $_POST['category'];
```

should be

```
$sub_category = $_POST['selectedcategory'];
```

since the name attribute of the select is "selectedcategory" and not "category", which is what the key in $_POST will be once the form is posted.